# Azure Copy Activity Rest Results Unexpected

Tags: azure-data-factory, square-connect

I'm attempting to pull data from the Square Connect v1 API using ADF.  I'm utilizing a Copy Activity with a REST source.  I am successfully pulling back data, however, the results are unexpected.

The endpoint is /v1/{location_id}/payments.  I have three parameters, shown below.
[image: Parameters]

I can successfully pull this data via Postman.

[image]

The results are stored in a Blob and are as if I did not specify any parameters whatsoever.
[image]

Only when I hardcode the parameters into the relative path 
[image]

do I get correct results.

[image]

I feel I must be missing a setting somewhere, but which one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try setting the values you want into a setVariable activity, and then have your copyActivity reference those variables.  This will tell you whether it is an issue with the dynamic content or not.  I have run into some unexpected behavior myself.  The benefit of the intermediate setVariable activity is twofold.  Firstly it coerces the datatype, secondly, it lets you see what the value is.

My apologies for not using comments.  I do not yet have enough points to comment.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll test this today.  After sleeping on it, I think I mistakenly assumed that the parameters in the activity were http request parameters, similar to Postman or similar REST tools.  Instead, I think they are parameters for the copy activity.

Comment: This was helpful.  After testing I realized my issue was confusing the parameters of the dataset for parameters of a REST resource.